# Errors when Install bower in mac

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, bower

```
zandeMacBook-Pro:reactQa root# bower -v
1.5.2
zandeMacBook-Pro:reactQa root# sudo bower init
bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo

Additional error details:
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any     necessary repairs.

http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

You can however run a command with sudo using --allow-root option
zandeMacBook-Pro:reactQa root#
```

Following the hint, I type:

```
sudo bower init --allow-root
```

Init successful. But error happened when install bootstrap.

I try to run `sudo bower install bootstrap --allow-root`

Output result is in below

```
zandeMacBook-Pro:reactQa root# sudo bower install bootstrap --allow-root
bower not-cached    git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower resolve       git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git", exit code of #69  You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements, please run 'xcodebuild -license' (for user-level acceptance) or 'sudo xcodebuild -license' (for system-wide acceptance) from within a Terminal window to review and agree to the Xcode license agreements.

Additional error details:
You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements, please run 'xcodebuild -license' (for user-level acceptance) or 'sudo xcodebuild -license' (for system-wide acceptance) from within a Terminal window to review and agree to the Xcode license agreements.
```

Any help?

Comment: So... did you run 'xcodebuild -license'?

Comment: Hammm....all I just needs to accept the license, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed in comment, running "xcodebuild -license" to accept the license fixed the problem. Make sure to always read error messages first.